# Why does this resolved Q promise responds to valueOf() with a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have an object whose value comes from an AJAX request. I'm converting it to a promise and am encountering some behaviour with promises that I don't expect. I have an example here that exhibits the same behaviour, but I'm substituting Q.all() for my AJAX request.

```
(Thing = function(){
  var promise;
  var refresh = function() {
    promise = Q.all(["a", "b"]);
  };

  var fetch = function(i) {
    return promise.then(function(promiseVal){
      return promiseVal[i];
    });
  };

  refresh();

  return {
    "fetch": fetch,
    "refresh": refresh,
    "promise": promise
  };

}());
```

Thing is executed on load and runs "refresh" to populate itself initially. The point of the "fetch" function is that my async request (Q.all in this case) returns a promise for an array, but what I really want is a promise for elements in the array (e.g. a promise for "a"  or a promise for "b"). So I'm expecting `Thing.fetch(1)` to return a promise for "b".

`Thing.fetch(1)` does return a promise, but if I do `Thing.fetch(1).valueOf()` it returns a promise, not "b" as I was expecting. If I do:

```
Thing.fetch(1).then(function(foo){
  console.log(foo);
});
```

it will print "b" on the console.

If I do `Thing.promise.valueOf()` it returns the array, so the promise is resolved when I call "fetch".

So my question is why doesn't valueOf() return a value when I call it on the promise returned by "fetch"?

Comment: Notice that by calling `Thing.refresh()` you do not alter the value of `Thing.promise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your promise is not resolved yet.

It's not well documented, but scattered over the wiki pages I found:

> The valueOf call returns the promise itself by default.
>
> The `valueOf` method is useful for providing information about the
>   promise in the same turn of the event loop. For example, resolved
>   promises return their resolution value and rejections return an object
>   that is recognized by isRejected.
>
> If the promise is fulfilled, `promise.valueOf()` returns the fulfilled
>   value. If the promise is or has forwarded to a deferred promise, it
>   returns most recently deferred promise. For rejected promises,
>   `promise.valueOf()` returns a sentinel object with
>   `{rejectedPromise: true, reason: {}}`

When you're doing `Thing.fetch(1).then(console.log);` it will of course print `"b"` on the console - that's the resolve value which is passed to the callback. But notice that it will invoke the log function in the future!

Comment: As far as I can tell the promise should be resolved. If I go `Thing.promise.valueOf()` it's resolved and I get ["a", "b"]. If I call `Thing.fetch(1).valueOf()` after that it returns a promise. I'm doing this by hand so it's not like I'm calling it too fast. 

If the promise returned by fetch() isn't resolved I'd like to know why before I can accept the answer.

Comment: `promise` is created as an already-resolved Promise. Yet, `then` [is guaranteed](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) to be asynchronous, so `Thing.fetch()` will yield a Promise that gets resolved in the future. See also [the Q tutorial](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#tutorial): "*resolution of a promise is always asynchronous*"

Comment: Ok. After some experimenting I understand what you're talking about. `Thing.fetch(1).valueOf()` all happens in the same turn of the event loop, so even though `promise` has resolved at this point the new promise from `fetch()` has NOT resolved, so `valueOf()` shows me the promise.

If I go `var a = Thing.fetch(1); a.valueOf();` I get the value for the promise because the event loop has ticked and the new promise from `fetch()` has resolved.  I'm going to clean up your answer a bit to make this explicit and then accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I was doing some more experimenting and I figured out that `var a = Thing.fetch(1); a.valueOf();` doesn't work. If I have it as two lines in the console it works, but if I add those lines in my file `a.valueOf()` remains a promise. So when will the promise returned by fetch be resolved?

Comment: In [Q's `nextTick`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnexttickcallback) - quite fast but after the current execution. If you execute them together it will be that same as `Thing.fetch(1).valueOf()` (and the next tick is after that execution), but when you use the console and submit it in two pieces, the tick will happen in between.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of the promise is an array.
The value of the function passed to "then" will be some value.
Your fetch method is not really returning a promise, it is resolving a promise.

Comment: Of course `fetch` is returning a promise, what else would it return?

Comment: The output of the then function it called?

Comment: And `then` does return… a Promise.